# Can one use NetTrain with two Nvidia GPUs?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, gpu

I am thinking of buying another GPU to accelerate my training. Will I be able to call NetTrain with both GPUs (`"TargetDevice"-> {"GPU", All}`)? Or would it be wasted money?

Best,
Max

Edit: What about SLI GPUs? Can I trick Mathematica into thinking its one GPU?

Comment: I don't think `NetTrain` allows for multi-GPU training at this point in time? Although this could have been implemented in 11.3, when I inquired about this in 11.2 I was told it wasn't possible.

Comment: I doubt they train all their pretrained `NetModel`s on only one GPU and if they train them in pure MXNet, some development to do as much as possible in Wolfram should be already in place.

Comment: I've tested it in Ubuntu 16.04 with Mathematica 11.3, but I encounted a problem about accuracy of training. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/181942/6648

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Multi-GPU support very nearly made it for 11.3, and it will definitely be available to users in 12. I will update this answer if it becomes available before that.

Regarding SLI: as far as I know, it has no relevance for CUDA-compute (only graphics rendering for games) and it won't 'trick' `NetTrain` into considering this as a single GPU.

Comment: Hi, Sebastian. I've just posted a question about two cards training in Mathematica 11.3, is it a bug? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/181942/6648