# Can you train ImageClassify model with multiple GPUs correctly?

Tags: neural-networks, mxnet-format

After some testing, I still cann't train with two GPU in Windows 10.

But I can train with Mathematica 11.3 in Ubuntu 16.04 with two graphics card GTX 1080

The problem is, If I use two card to train, the model is not so trainable as we can see the loss curve in the following pictures.
Not the reason of BatchSize's setting, I've tested the BatchSize Value From 50 to 250 in the case of `TargetDevice->{"GPU",All}`.

Is this a bug?

[image: Trainable use One GPU]

[image: Two GPU]

You may try the MNIST example

```
NetTrain[NetModel["LeNet"], trainingData, ValidationSet -> testData, TargetDevice->{"GPU",All}]
```

Comment: According to [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/170721/57593), multiple GPU training isn't currently functional in Mathematica 11.3. I'd guess 12 is coming soon, hopefully multi-GPU will be in that release.